# Hibernate - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm getting this error while updating an Entity in a Spring Boot application.

I have this 2 objects

```
@Entity
public class User {
...
@ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="locationId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Location> locations;
...
//getters and setters
}
```

then

```
 @Entity
    public class Coupon {

    .....
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<Location> locations;
    ....
    //getters and setters
    }
```

In a scheduler i need to interact with both User and Coupon

```
List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();
locations.addAll(user.getLocations());
Coupon coupon = couponService.generateCoupons(CouponType.TIME   , contract.getType().getTimeCredit(), locations, couponName);
    userService updateUser(user);
```

`generateCoupons` is in a `@Service` and `@Transactional` class;

```
@Override
    public Coupon generateCoupons(CouponType type, int value, List<Location> locations, String couponName) {
        Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
        coupon.setActive(true);
        coupon.setCode(generateRandomCouponCode());
        coupon.setCouponCount(0);
        coupon.setCouponLimit(1);
        coupon.setCouponName(couponName);
        LocalDateTime limit = LocalDateTime.now().plusYears(1);
        coupon.setDateLimit(Date.from(limit.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
        coupon.setLocations(locations);
        coupon.setStartDate(new Date());
        coupon.setType(type);
        coupon.setUserLimit(1);
        coupon.setValue(value);

        return saveCoupon(coupon);
    }
```

when trying to persist the Coupon i get the exception, i don't know why, everything happens in a Transaction...

this is the complete stack trace

```
aused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: it.besmart.eshare.persistence.model.User.locations, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.addAll(PersistentBag.java:328)
    at it.besmart.eshare.service.CouponService.generateCoupons(CouponService.java:248)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy171.generateCoupons(Unknown Source)
    at it.besmart.eshare.scheduler.cronjobs.CheckContract.executeInternal(CheckContract.java:102)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: sure, i edited the question

Comment: I'm not sure the stacktrace match with the code shared, or maybe I'm missing something, which one is line 248 in CouponService?

Comment: It’s the saveCoupon(coupon) row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, session management configuration is set to close session when you commit transaction.
It's a good practice to immediately fetch lazy entities if you are going to work with them. Like in this JPQL query:

```
select User u from User join fetch u.locations
```

Otherwise, getting the user and then getting the location should be wrapped in a transactional method. In your case, hibernate tries to get locations, but sees that there is already no session to which he was attached. You need to define @Transaction method will start where you get the user, as I understood in scheduler.
But be careful, the main thing is not to delay with the duration of the transaction, so for pure work with the data, you should create a separate @Transactional method.

Comment: Thanks, i solved getting the user inside the transactional method generateCoupons

Answer (score 1):

Sir, here you didnt specify fetch type eager. By default it's lazy fetch. 
 But you trying to fetch it Eagerly. So One exception 
 happens here.

```
         user. getLocation();//Failed to lazy initialize User. 
         // locations the Exception what we seen in console
```

Just modify User model class like this

```
       @ManytoMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinColumn(name="locationId")
        @JsonIgnore
        private List<Location> locations;
```